# JAVA Simulation error when using Cooja mote in Contiki-ng

Tags: java, jvm, contiki, cooja, contiki-ng

I'm trying to do a simulation in Cooja simulator, Contiki-ng using cooja motes and CSMA and the energest model.
Even though the simulation works well in Z1 mote with cooja motes the simulation stops and I get a null pointer error:

```
[15:19:20 - Thread-1] [Simulation.java:308] [FATAL] - Simulation stopped due to error: null
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.contikios.cooja.contikimote.ContikiMoteType.getCoreMemory(ContikiMoteType.java:824) ~[cooja.jar:?]
at org.contikios.cooja.contikimote.ContikiMote.execute(ContikiMote.java:149) ~[cooja.jar:?]
at org.contikios.cooja.motes.AbstractWakeupMote$1.execute(AbstractWakeupMote.java:51) ~[cooja.jar:?]
at org.contikios.cooja.Simulation.run(Simulation.java:296) ~[cooja.jar:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[?:?]
```

When I try to do the same simulation with TSCH, 6TiSCH 6top and add the energest model I get this error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f893449310d, pid=723817, tid=724266
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (11.0.15+10) (build 11.0.15+10-LTS)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (11.0.15+10-LTS, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0xa5710d]  Klass::search_secondary_supers(Klass*) const+0xd
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t %c %h %e" (or dumping to usr/contiki-ng/tools/cooja/build/core.723817)
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Red%20Hat%20Enterprise%20Linux%208&component=java-11-openjdk
```

a quick search says it's a bug, but as it only occurs when I add the energy model I'm not sure!

Comment: It seems that lot of people have similar problems with this library: https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/issues/2618